# VBA split string sentences with multiple values

Tags: vba

My Excel raw data looks something like this:

;123456p,Roses and butterflies;;124456h,Violets are blue;

;123456d,Hello world;

- Expected output:
- Roses and butterflies
- Violets are blue
- Hello world

Trying to split the text sentences out only, for rows with multiple sentences I would need them in
separate rows, is this at all possible? Below is what I tried.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_click()
    Dim splitstring As String
    Dim myarray() As String
    splitstring = Worksheets("raw").Cells(1, 1).Value
    myarray = Split(splitstring, ";")
    For i = 0 To URound(myarray)

    Next

End Sub

Sub raw()

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please add expected output once? so that we can think further?

Comment: added it in there, expected output is that each sentence goes into a row of its own, in instances where multi values are present, so it would increment by 1 every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Regular Expressions, you can populate Column B with the desired results ae below

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_click()

Dim wSh As Worksheet
Dim rngStr As String, rngStrArr() As String, i As Long
Set wSh = Worksheets("raw")
Dim regEx As Object, mc As Object
Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

regEx.Global = True
regEx.IgnoreCase = True

rngStr = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(( _
        wSh.Range("A1:A" & wSh.Cells(wSh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)), 0, 1)))
regEx.Pattern = ",([^;]+);"
Set mc = regEx.Execute(rngStr)
rngStr = ""
For i = 0 To mc.Count - 1
    rngStr = rngStr & mc(i)
Next i

rngStr = Replace(rngStr, ",", "")

rngStrArr = Split(rngStr, ";")

wSh.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(rngStrArr), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(rngStrArr)

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private sub SplitString()
Dim splitstring As String
Dim myarray() As String
splitstring = Cells(1, 1).Value
myarray = Split(splitstring, ",")

For i = 1 To UBound(myarray)
    MsgBox (myarray(i))
Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: says invalid outside procedure

Comment: @patpat91 Wrap it in a `Sub ... End Sub`. @DarrenPeterson Index in VBA starts at 0. Better use the `LBound()` function.